# Vector class in c++ programing

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Can anybody explain me, what is use of vector class?  My Professor mentioned about below sentence in the lecture.
Template: Each vector has a class parameter that determines which object type will be used by that instance, usually called T. I don't understand what exactly class parameters means?

Comment: Did you ask your teacher?

Comment: btw how did yesterday's homework about the chopstick sorting work out for you?

Comment: Its going good I think I am going to finish it today. Well thanks for asking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector is defined as a template like:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector;
```

To use it you need to instantiate the template like:

```
Vector<char> myVector;
```

Instantiating a vector effectively creates a new class. which is equivalent to what you would get if you'd replaced every occurrence of T in the definition of the template with the class argument (in this case char)

So if we had a simple template

```
template<typename T>
class DataHolder{ 
public:
 T data
}
```

Instantiated like:

```
DataHolder<char> myChar;
```

Is equivalent to the class:

```
class DataHolder
{
public:
 char data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, feels much better about question

Answer (score 13):

The `vector` type in C++ is essentially a dynamic array.  The class parameter is the type of the elements within the `vector`.  For example

```
int arr[];  // Static C++ array with int elements
vector<int> v; // dynamic array with int elements
```

In this example `int` is the class parameter type.

**EDIT**

As several comments pointed out the choice of "class parameter" by your teacher is misleading.  It's more correct to say "template parameter".

Comment: For clarity: the "class parameter" is (in essence) of type "class" (although it can be a primitive, so maybe "type")

Comment: I agree- calling it a class is misleading as you can pass primitives. This ain't Java.

Comment: It's really a template parameter anyway, and its type is `typename` IIRC.

Comment: Agreed that the term chosen by the teacher is a bit odd but perhaps it's due to the class keyword as in template<class T>

Comment: @Rune FS: while the use of `class` is possible, it is recommend to use `typename` instead. `class` was used first because there was reluctance for the introduction of a new keyword, however it is both confusing (since you can pass built-in types or `struct`) and render the meaning of the keyword context dependent.

Comment: @Matthieu I totally agree. Personally I don't use <class> I've worked with plenty'o devs that thought it ment you could only pass a class. I don't call it a class argument either (except here for consistency with OPs use of terms) but just tried to point out that a person who write template<class T> might call T a class argument. I'm sorry if it seemed as a recommendation of that use

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

This declares a `vector` (dynamic array) of `int` elements. Initially it contains space for zero elements.

The web contains many resources about basic C++. See for example [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/vector.html) for more about STL `vector`s.

Comment: My professor gave me cplusplus.com website for reference but I think the website you gave is much easier to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

these two videos give very good explaination about stl and its containers iterators usages.

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Introduction-to-STL-with-Stephan-T-Lavavej/

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-2-of-n/